# Definition second differential of a vector field

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth function.
Then we know that its differential $df: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow Hom(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$ maps vectors to matrices/linear maps.

But how do we define $D^2 f$? Is it defined like $D^2f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow Hom(\mathbb{R}^2, Hom(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2))$ (and in this case: how do I write it explicitly?) or is it defined like $D^2 f(y)(z,w) := D(Df(y)(w))(z)$ or like something else?
In the [solutions of the problem 5.2 of this problem sheet](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2016/math/nm2/Assignment5sol.pdf) there's this ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sRTj.png)).

I don't understand why does $D^2f$ have two arguments, $w$ and $z$.

Is it possible to generalize the whole thing for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the geometric interpretation, but this might be a way to find your $D^2$.

Similarly to your intuition, think of $D^2f(x)(v,w)$ as the derivative of $$x\mapsto Df(x)v=:G_v(x)$$ in direction $w$. Then you can easily check by hand that the two definitions agree.

Of course this easily generalizes to maps $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ via the same definition, and similarly 
$$D^kf(x)(v_1,\dots,v_k)$$
can be defined recursively in the same way.